# Calculating Future time in MS SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables as below\

**Table-1**

Order_ID(Numeric)---Order_Date(Datetime)

100067           ---     2013-08-30 09:54:47.000

100068           ---     2013-08-30 10:30:37.000

**Table-2**

Order_ID(Numeric)---Order_Date(Datetime)              ---Delivery_Time(Datetime)

100067           ---     2013-08-30 09:54:47.000

100068           ---     2013-08-30 10:30:37.000

Now i want to calculate the delivery time by one hour from order time. For example my order time in Table-1 is 2013-08-30 09:54:47.000 i want to insert a record in table-2 with Delivery_Time as 2013-08-30 10:54:47.000. Ultimately i want to add 1 hour to the order time in table-1 and insert the record in table-2.

Can you please help me out with this situation.

Comment: Could you perhaps share what you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: If `Delivery_Time` is *always* one hour after `Order_Date`, you shouldn't store it independently, and should instead consider e.g. a computed column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE2    
 select ORDER_ID,DATEADD(HH,1,ORDER_DATE) FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: Thank q very much Sonam..Its working..I was been trying this from past 4 hours and did not find a soluytion in google as well.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the DateAdd function:

```
 DATEADD(hh, 1, Order_Date)
```

Breaking this down, the DATEADD function requires the date part, the value to add, and the target of the operation. In this case, hours, one, and Order_Date.